# How can I optimise a SQL query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am new to SQL query things. Below SQL query is taking almost 4 minutes to run because of which page remains stuck for that much time. We need to optimise this query so that user is not stuck there for that much time.

How can I optimise this?

We are using Oracle db.

```
SELECT abc_app_request.id                     AS FINANCE_REQUEST_ID, 
       abc_app_request.finance_request_status AS FINACE_REQUEST_STATUS, 
       abc_app_request.dnb_credit_amount      AS DNB_CREDIT_AMOUNT, 
       abc_app.id                             AS CONFIRMATION_NUMBER, 
       abc_app.country_code                   AS COUNTRY_CODE, 
       abc_country.NAME                       AS COUNTRY_NAME, 
       abc_app.agent_id                       AS AGENT, 
       abc_app.territory_id                   AS TERRITORY_ID, 
       abc_customer.NAME                      AS CUSTOMER_NAME, 
       abc_app.created_date                   AS CREATED_DATE, 
       abc_app_request.finance_request_status AS STATUS, 
       abc_equipment.terms_amount_requested   AS TERMS_AMOUNT_REQUESTED, 
       abc_equipment.lease_amount_requested   AS LEASE_AMOUNT_REQUESTED, 
       abc_app_request.amount                 AS APPROVED_AMOUNT, 
       aaa_soldto_xyz.sold_to_acct        AS SOLD_TO, 
       CASE 
         WHEN abc_customer_address.zip_code IS NULL THEN (SELECT ADDR.zip_code 
                                                          FROM 
         abc_customer_address ADDR 
                                                          WHERE  ADDR.id = 
       abc_customer.billing 
                                                                 AND rownum = 1) 
         ELSE abc_customer_address.zip_code 
       END                                    AS ZIP_CODE, 
       abc_app_request.finance_option_id      AS FINANCING_OPTION, 
       abc_customer.ivparameter               AS IVPARAMETER, 
       abc_customer.primary_phone             AS PRIMARY_PHONE, 
       abc_customer.office_phone              AS OFFICE_PHONE, 
       abc_app.agent_id                       AS AGENT_INFO, 
       abc_agent.person_id                    AS AGENT_PERSON_ID, 
       abc_finance_option.code                AS FINANCING_CODE 
FROM   abc_app 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_agent 
                    ON abc_app.agent_id = abc_agent.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_country 
                    ON abc_country.long_code = abc_app.country_code 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN aaa_soldto_xyz 
                    ON ( abc_app.id = Substr(aaa_soldto_xyz.xyz_id, 0, 6) 
                          OR abc_app.id = Substr(aaa_soldto_xyz.xyz_id, 1, 
                                          Length 
                                          ( 
                                          aaa_soldto_xyz.xyz_id) - 5) ), 
       abc_customer 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_customer_detail 
                    ON abc_customer_detail.id = abc_customer.customer_detail 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_customer_address 
                    ON ( abc_customer_detail.trade_addr = 
                         abc_customer_address.id 
                          OR abc_customer_address.id = 
                             abc_customer.physical_address ), 
       abc_app_request 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_finance_option 
                    ON abc_app_request.finance_option_id = abc_finance_option.id 
       , 
       abc_equipment 
WHERE  abc_app.customer_id = abc_customer.id 
       AND abc_app_request.application_id = abc_app.id 
       AND abc_app.equipment_information = abc_equipment.id 
       AND ( abc_app_request.finance_request_status = 1 ) 
       AND 1 = 1 
ORDER  BY abc_app.id DESC
```

Comment: We don't know anything about your data or the table structures or indexes etc.. You should start by looking at the execution plan. You are mixing old-style joins (comma-separated tables) with ANSI joins, which is confusing to read and can break things, but may also be confusing the optimiser as it will restrict the order joins can happen; so maybe fix that before you dig too much further.

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements can be made by having 2 pre-computed columns in `aaa_soldto_xyz` table:

`aaa_soldto_xyz.ID1 = Substr(aaa_soldto_xyz.xyz_id, 0, 6)`

`aaa_soldto_xyz.ID2 = Substr(aaa_soldto_xyz.xyz_id, 1, Length ( aaa_soldto_xyz.xyz_id) - 5) )`

Those can make better use of existing or new indexes.

Answer (score 0):

We can not help you in optimizing the query without explain plan.

But obvious improvement needed in this query is: remove `abc_customer_address` table from subquery(select clause) and do left join in from list and check for the result.

You need to change following clauses.

From clause

```
Left join (SELECT ADDR.zip_code, 
ADDR.ID, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADDR.ID ORDER BY 1) AS RN                                                     
FROM abc_customer_address ADDR                                                          
WHERE  ADDR.id = abc_customer.billing                                                              ) ADDR 
ON (ADDR.id = abc_customer.billing AND ADDR.RN = 1)
```

Select clause:

```
CASE WHEN abc_customer_address.zip_code IS NULL THEN ADDR.zip_code
ELSE abc_customer_address.zip_code 
END AS ZIP_CODE,
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thnx Tejaash, i will check

Comment: I have updated the from clause. Added partition by clause in row_number. Please use the latest code